# Duda con entidades

Tags: laravel, mvc, eloquent, backend

Estoy desarrollando un backend tipo tinder con laravel y tengo una duda al relacionar dos entidades.

El problema me viene en esta parte:

```
Entidad Usuario
Entidad Match
```

En la entidad match quiero relacionar a dos usuarios con claves foráneas de ambos (id) y que una vez ambos se den me gusta en el front, se cree una columna match con lo dicho.

Mi miedo es que se me creen dos insertos distintos con:

```
Match 1   Id_user1   Id_user2

Match 2   Id_user2   Id_user1
```

Quiero evitar esto ya que solo quiero un match.

El resultado final quiero que sea

```
Match 1   Id_user 1   Id_user2
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes resolverlo de varias formas, pero creo que estás confundiendo un poco la lógica desde el punto de vista cronológico.

Los eventos serían algo así:

1. Usuario 1 da **like** (me gusta) a usuario 2
2. Usuario 2 da **like** (megusta) a usuario 1
3. El match (coincidencia) es generado

En ese orden de ideas podrías tener dos tablas: una que almacene los **like** (me gusta) y otra que almacene los **match** (coincidencias).

¿Por qué más de una tabla? Porque si manejaras todo en una sola tabla pivote como lo planteas, no tienes una trazabilidad adecuada de cuando algun usuario da like a otro (teniendo en cuenta que no siempre se genera un match), y las búsquedas para determinarlo podrían ser engorrosas.

Una solución práctica para la tabla de **likes** es utilizar las relaciones polimórficas de Laravel, la cual abstrae un poco estas entidades y permite una gestión flexible de los likes (en este caso), además de hacerlo escalable, revisa su documentación:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración Shaz, voy a intentar hacerlo como tú dices con las polimórficas.

<3